# Checkout/onepage not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I'm having trouble fixing the onepage checkout system. The checkout page buttons don't let you go to the next step, I'm assuming this is the javascript?

[image]

In the console it is displaying a few errors but mainly this one:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Validation is not a constructor
    at d.save (opcheckout.js:353)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):565)
```

Comment: wich magento version ?

Comment: seems like jQuery and prototype confict each other

Comment: My Magento version is 1.9 and how do I fix the conflict please? @SunilPatel

Comment: @user55794 i need to check which file called before, basically you need to call jQuery then no coflict then prototype

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Magento and developing is there an easy way to do this? @SunilPatel

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add below line into `index.php`

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Then check the checkout, view source and you will got the current error.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason when i inspect the page the JS link doesn't include
>   www, but when I test adding www on a local it works !. How do I add
>   this to the .phtml template ?

If your website does not work without **www** - add a nginx\htaccess 301 rewrite from non-www to www domain for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It will not solve the issue itself for sure - you still need to find that link and correct, however it will prevent issues to appear in various unexpected places, so your Live website for example - will not broke again suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your theme that your are using doesn't contain `validation.js`, try to add it via l**ocal.xml** `app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
</reference>
```